# Estimating Entropy From Stream of Integers

Tags: java, algorithm, probability-theory, information-theory

I have a continuous stream of integers across the space of all the 32-bit integers, and upon each update I want to know either the exact or approximate entropy of the distributions of integers I have encountered. It can be global entropy across the lifetime or a windowed approximation that attenuates older information as time passes.

Does anyone know of a library that does this already or an algorithm that has this property?

Clearly, this is a streaming algorithm as it is too expensive to iterate over the range each time and calculate the entropy on each update. Does anyone know of such an algorithm or sketch data structure that can do this?

The motivation and use case is that I want to detect skew in the stream of integers. It is supposed to be uniform across the range of integers but at certain times, due to other conditions, the uniformity may be disturbed and I think entropy is the best way to detect this kind of condition. I'd ideally have an alert on low entropy for the calculating component.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I actually found a paper that does exactly [this](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS49-Fall11/Papers/chakrabarti-entropy.pdf) but I know of no existing implementation. Reusing tested, verified code would be way better than having to implement it myself. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, since you have already found a reference that explains how to do what you need, as you say, I don't see how your question could be answered otherwise than with providing fully coded solutions or library recommendations and both are considered off-topic here.